# Delphi: Set ImageBase bigger than 32-bit (for 64-bit Windows application)

Tags: delphi, winapi, 64-bit

I have been playing with the `{$IMAGEBASE}` directive in Delphi but I can see that I can only put a value lower than `$FFFFFFFF` (32-bit).

I'm compiling as x64 and I need to set an image base bigger than 32-bit but Delphi ignores the higher 32-bit DWORD in my 64-bit ImageBase.

Has anyone managed to set a value higher than `$FFFFFFFF` as ImageBase for Delphi?

I need it because I need to test my application in "high" ImageBase (due to some hook tests, etc)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are running Windows 7 (or earlier) you could enable the [nolowmem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542202.aspx) boot option, and have your application automatically loaded into addresses above the 4 GB boundary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Delphi linker does not support large image base, although there are new PE optional headers that allow large image base values to be specified.

So I think that until Embarcadero introduce any such functionality, you would need to use a third party tool to rebase the executable file after it has been built. For instance [EDITBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/editbin-reference) with the [/REBASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rebase) option from the MS toolchain.

I took a simple 64 bit VCL program, built with XE7, and rebased it like this:

```
editbin /rebase:base=0xffffff0000 Project1.exe
```

I confirmed using Process Hacker that the image base was indeed as specified.

[image]

Comment: or use `link.exe /edit /rebase:base=* Project1.exe` because `editbin.exe <cmdline>` simply invoke `link.exe /edit <cmdline>` and of course  for this image need build with relocation enabled, without this (relocs) rebase failed